# onStartLoading gets called multiple times

Tags: android, loader

I'm having an issue with Android `Loaders`.
I have an activity populated from internet data, and I have a bookmarks option to store and load them locally.
I'm implementing a `recyclerView` displaying the items.
When I change the sorting criteria the `adapter` gets cleared and repopulated with new data, and when I choose to see the bookmarked items a local query is started to the `ContentProvider`.
Now, I'm having issues with the bookmarked data, since I get multiple copies of the same item in my `adapter`.
I've done some logging and I noted that the loader is called multiple times when loading locally (adding the same items each time), but I can't see why.
Note that this occurs also when I get back to the activity, but does not occur when I start the app with the bookmarks preference.
If I start from bookmarks, select a bookmark and go back, multiple calls are done, too.
Can anyone help me? Here's the code:
In `MainActivity` this method is called at the end of `onCreate`

```
 private void loadPosters() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Loading posters");
    if (mPagesLoaded < MAX_PAGES) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page",mPagesLoaded+1);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID,args,this);
    }
}
```

My loader code:

```
public Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle args) {
    return new AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Movie>>(this) {
        ArrayList<Movie> mData;

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            Log.d(TAG,"Start Loading");
            super.onStartLoading();
            if (mData!=null){
                deliverResult(mData);
            }else{
                if (mPagesLoaded == 0) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                mErrorTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                forceLoad();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<Movie> loadInBackground() {
            Log.d(TAG,"Load in background");
            if (args.size() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            int page = args.getInt("page");
            NetworkUtils networker = new NetworkUtils(getApplicationContext());
            String criterion = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.movie_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("sorting", "popular");
            if (!(criterion.equals(getString(R.string.pref_bookmarked)))) {
                URL request = networker.buildMoviesUrl(page, criterion);
                try {
                    String JSONResponse = networker.getResponseFromHttpUrl(request);
                    ArrayList<Movie> res =  fetchMoviesFromJson(JSONResponse);
                    mPagesLoaded++;
                    return res;

                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Local Loading");
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
                if (cursor!=null){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Cursor is not null");
                    ArrayList<Movie> res = fetchMoviesFromCursor(cursor);
                    cursor.close();
                    return res;
                }
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void deliverResult(ArrayList<Movie> data) {
            mData = data;
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }
    };
}
```

My `onLoadFinished` callback:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> loader, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Load finished");
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (movies != null) {
        mPostersAdapter.addMovies(movies);
        Log.d(TAG,mPostersAdapter.getItemCount() + " items loaded");
        showPosters();
    } else {
        showErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

And my `SharedPreferences` code:

```
private void initSharedPreferences() {
    mSharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("movie_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Shared preferences for " + key + "changed. Pref: " + sharedPreferences.getString(key, null));
            mPagesLoaded = 0;
            mPostersAdapter.clear();
            loadPosters();
        }
    };
    mSharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener);

}
```

Comment: did you find the problem?

Comment: At that time I managed to solve the problem but now I don't remember what I did. It's a shame I forgot to post the solution, I'm really sorry about this

Answer (score 1):

I had to call `destoryLoader()` on loader Manager, to solve this. Not sure if this is the right way..

Comment: I think it had to do with the load on scrolling. Few bookmarks, Android thought that I was at the end of the line and then loaded again. Something like that I guess. I suppose I've fixed that in this commit:
https://github.com/magicleon94/Popular-Movies-Stage-2/commit/e79043738b9bf9f0dd2535733890b0fdc561c89c

I hope this can help you, I'm really sorry for not being able to do more